# What is the means of full measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry

In this [paper](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/sevcl150427.pdf), as picture below, what is the mean of proof of Lemma 2.3?  I absolutly can't understand it. And how to get almost any $\epsilon > 0$ is regular from Sard theorem ? Sard theorem just say  critical set  has measure 0.

I want a way , if $Z_\phi$ is density in $S$ , then , $\forall x\in Z_\phi$ , I can find $\{x_n\}\subset Z_\phi$ and $x_n\rightarrow x$ , then 
$$
\nabla\phi(x)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\phi(x_n)-\phi(x)}{x_n-x}=0
$$
But , how to show $Z_\phi$ is density in $S$ ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: "Full measure" means the complement has measure zero.  Here, almost all points of $Z_\phi$ are points of density.

Comment: @GEdgar   I add my understand in my question. But I fail to prove some keypoint, could you help me ? besides, what is the mean of "points of density"  ?